# AngularJS - как задать несколько условий для одного ng-if?

Tags: html5, angularjs

Есть две section

`<section class="flex-fluid-container" ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.1,2,3,4')">`

и

`<section class="flex-fluid-container" ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.5')" id="admin">`

Есть 5 пунктов в меню.

Нужно, чтобы в 4 активных `<section...` открывался `<section...` без id="admin",

а в 5 `<section... id="admin"` с id="admin".

Можно задать сразу несколько условий для `ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.1,2,3,4')"`?

`<section class="flex-fluid-container" ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.1,2,3,4')">` не работает,

работает `<section class="flex-fluid-container" ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.1')">`

В моем варианте, условия это

dashboard.1

dashboard.2

dashboard.3

dashboard.4

dashboard.5

**Возможно, есть решение проще и можно создать противоположное от 
`<section class="flex-fluid-container" ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.1,2,3,4')">` прописав условие, чтобы не открывалось на dashboard.5**

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-if="utils.stateIs('dashboard.1') || utils.stateIs('dashboard.2') || ..."
```

Попробуйте добавить оператор ||, оператор && тоже работает

Немного не понятная задача. Почему нельзя разбить на 4 div-а, а в 5 div добавить id="admin"?